# Is there a way of drawing a colormap with non monotonicaly increasing coordinates? mapping of a colormap

Tags: python, mapping, colormap, coordinate-transformation

(in python)

For a project I am working on mappings from one complex coordinate system to another. In the initial system (x/y plane, with z=x+iy) I define a potential. After mapping I want to draw this same potential in the new coordinate system (u/v plane with w=u+iv).
I visualise the potential using colormaps/contourf, and it works really well in the x/y-plane, however, after mapping my coordinates for the potential arent in a square/monotically increasing grid anymore. This breaks the colormap. Is there a function that does not need square coordinates/monotone increasing ones, that can interpolate the correct colors? Or does anyone know how I can program this myself?

As you see in the picture below the colormap is not transformed in the same way the lines are. The lines are mapped the same way as the colormap coordinates, and they work properly, so I think the idea behind my code is solid, it's just a wrong input for the contour/colormap functions.

[What colormap gives me. I want the colormap to follow the transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqg6M.png)

The important bits of code, pot is my potential, g(z) is my mapping from z to w:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xdomain = [-np.pi,np.pi]
ydomain = [0,3]
udomain = [-4,4]
vdomain = [-4,4]
gridsize = 20

#potential function
def pot(z):
    return np.imag(z)

#conformal mapping from z to w
def g(z):
    return np.sin(z)

#x's and y's for the colormap grid
x = np.linspace(xdomain[0]/2,xdomain[1]/2,gridsize)
y = np.linspace(ydomain[0],ydomain[1],gridsize)
w = g(x+1j*y)
z = np.array([pot(i+1j*j) for j in y for i in x])
Z = z.reshape(gridsize,gridsize)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax[0][0].contourf(x,y, Z)
ax[1][0].contourf(np.real(w),np.imag(w),Z)

ax[0][0].set_xlim(xdomain)
ax[0][0].set_ylim(ydomain)
ax[0][0].set_title('z-plane')

ax[1][0].set_xlim(udomain)
ax[1][0].set_ylim(vdomain)
ax[1][0].set_title('w-plane')
```

Sometimes I get the following warning (this one happened when I tried the pcolormesh command instead of the contour command):

```
C:\###\conf_map.py:103: UserWarning: The input coordinates to pcolormesh
are interpreted as cell centers, but are not monotonically increasing 
or decreasing. This may lead to incorrectly calculated cell edges,
in which case, please supply explicit cell edges to pcolormesh.
ax[1][0].pcolormesh(np.real(w),np.imag(w),Z, shading='auto')
```

I tried changing the contour function to different colormap functions (image, pcolormesh etc, but all seemed to have the same problem)

Comment: the supplied code does not produce the supplied image, the lines in w-plane are Cartesian (straight)

Answer (score 0):

I found out I was transforming my coordinate system wrong. It now works! The 'w=g(x+1j*y)' line has to be replaced by:

```
U, V = np.meshgrid(x,y)
w = g(U+1j*V)
```

[This results in this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkkLC.png)

Also I changed the heatmap type (but it would work both ways):

```
ax[0][0].pcolormesh(x,y, Z, shading='gouraud', cmap='RdBu')
ax[1][0].pcolormesh(np.real(w),np.imag(w),Z, shading='gouraud', cmap='RdBu')
```

For those wondering how I draw the grid (@rioV8), I first make curves that draw the normal grid, and then transform them. Code for that looks like this (below should work without the other code):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xdomain = [-np.pi/2,np.pi/2]
ydomain = [0,2]

steps = 50
axxes = [21,31]

#mapping
def g(z):
    return np.sin(z)

#axxes[0] amount of x-axes drawn with steps amount of points
xaxes = np.linspace(xdomain[0],xdomain[1],axxes[0]) #real part of input
ystep = np.linspace(ydomain[0],ydomain[1],steps) #imaginary part of input
Xax, Yst = np.meshgrid(xaxes,ystep)

#Same for y-axes
xstep = np.linspace(xdomain[0],xdomain[1],steps)
yaxes = np.linspace(ydomain[0],ydomain[1],axxes[1])
Yax, Xst = np.meshgrid(yaxes,xstep)

#transform x and y-axes. calling them u and v is quite a misnomer
#w = u + iv
u = g(Xst + 1j*Yax) 
v = g(Xax + 1j*Yst) #Plugging the real and imaginary parts into the function

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,4)

#Draw the normal grid
[ax[0][0].plot(Xst[:,i], Yax[:,i], color='gray', linewidth=0.5)  for i in range(len(Yax[0]))]
[ax[0][0].plot(Xax[:,i], Yst[:,i], color='gray', linewidth=0.5)  for i in range(len(Xax[0]))]
ax[0][0].set_xlim(xdomain)
ax[0][0].set_ylim(ydomain)
ax[0][0].set_title('z-plane')

#draw the transformed grid
xts = ax[1][0].plot(np.real(u),np.imag(u), color='gray', linewidth=0.5)#, label=xaxes)
yts = ax[1][0].plot(np.real(v),np.imag(v), color='gray', linewidth=0.5)
ax[1][0].set_title('w-plane')
```

Comment: how do you get the curved grid in W-plane

Comment: @rioV8 I added the code for the grid of the z/w-plane in my answer

Comment: why use a list comprehension to draw a couple of lines, it costs extra computation to construct the list, and you don't use those lines later on

Comment: @rioV8 Initially I had a lot of trouble getting that piece to work. Now I realize that:
    ax[0][0].plot(Xst, Yax, color='gray', linewidth=0.5)
    ax[0][0].plot(Xax, Yst, color='gray', linewidth=0.5) 
Also does the trick and is probably way better